# how to groupby rows and create new columns on pyspark

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, group-by

original dataframe

| id | email | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | id1@first.com | john |
| 2 | id2@first.com | Maike |
| 2 | id2@second | Maike |
| 1 | id1@second.com | john |

I want to convert to this

| id | email | email1 | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | id1@first.com | id1@second.com | john |
| 2 | id2@first.com | id2@second | Maike |

it's only an example, I have very large file and more than 60 columns

im using

```
df = spark.read.option("header",True) \
        .csv("contatcs.csv", sep =',')
```

but works to with pyspark.pandas api

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps    

df = ps.read_csv('contacts.csv', sep=',')
df.head()
```

but I prefer spark.read because it's a Lazy Evaluation
and the pandas API is not

Comment: What is your criteria to create email columns? Is it based on domain like "first.com" or by name?

Comment: What you want is a `pivot`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**pyspark**

I have included a corner case when there is uneven number of email ids. For that, find the max length and iterate to fetch email at each index:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 'id1@first.com', 'john'),(2, 'id2@first.com', 'Maike'),(2, 'id2@second', 'Maike'),(1, 'id1@second.com', 'john'),(3, 'id3@third.com', 'amy'),], ['id', 'email', 'name'])

df = df.groupby("id", "name").agg(F.collect_list("email").alias("email"))
max_len = df.select(F.size("email").alias("size")).collect()[0]["size"]
for i in range(1, max_len + 1):
  df = df.withColumn(f"email{i}", F.when(F.size("email") >= i, F.element_at("email", i)).otherwise(F.lit("")))
df = df.drop("email")
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+-------------+--------------+
|id |name |email1       |email2        |
+---+-----+-------------+--------------+
|2  |Maike|id2@first.com|id2@second    |
|3  |amy  |id3@third.com|              |
|1  |john |id1@first.com|id1@second.com|
+---+-----+-------------+--------------+
```

**pandas**

Since you have mentioned pandas in the tags, following is the solution in pandas:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[(1, 'id1@first.com', 'john'),(2, 'id2@first.com', 'Maike'),(2, 'id2@second', 'Maike'),(1, 'id1@second.com', 'john'),(3, 'id3@third.com', 'amy'),], columns=["id","email","name"])

df = df.groupby("id").agg(email=("email",list), name=("name",pd.unique))
df2 = df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(data={f"email{i+1}":v for i,v in enumerate(row["email"])}, dtype="object"), axis=1)
df = df.drop("email", axis=1).merge(df2, on="id")
```

Output:

```
     name         email1          email2
id                                      
1    john  id1@first.com  id1@second.com
2   Maike  id2@first.com      id2@second
3     amy  id3@third.com             NaN
```

Comment: Both solution works, but your solution is better because is a large file and I didn't know how much email and duplicate IDs column! However, range(1, max_len + 1): cost a lot of process  ! thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to make it dynamic so that it creates new email counts based on maximum email count, you can try logic and code below

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('1', 'id1@first.com', 'john'),
     ('2', 'id2@first.com', 'Maike'),
     ('2', 'id2_3@first.com', 'Maike'),
     ('2', 'id2@second', 'Maike'),
     ('1', 'id1@second.com', 'john')],
    ['id', 'email', 'name'])

df.show()



+---+---------------+-----+
| id|          email| name|
+---+---------------+-----+
|  1|  id1@first.com| john|
|  2|  id2@first.com|Maike|
|  2|id2_3@first.com|Maike|
|  2|     id2@second|Maike|
|  1| id1@second.com| john|
```

Solution

```
new = (   df.groupBy('id','name').agg(collect_set('email').alias('email') )#Collect unique emails
        .withColumn('x',max(size('email')).over(Window.partitionBy()))#Find the group with maximum emails, for use in email column count
    )
     
new = (new.withColumn('email',F.struct(*[ F.col("email")[i].alias(f"email{i+1}") for i in range(new.select('x').collect()[0][0])]))#Convert email column to struct type
      .selectExpr('x','id','name','email.*') #Select all columns
     )
new.show(truncate=False)
```

Outcome

```
+---+---+-----+-------------+--------------+---------------+
|x  |id |name |email1       |email2        |email3         |
+---+---+-----+-------------+--------------+---------------+
|3  |1  |john |id1@first.com|id1@second.com|null           |
|3  |2  |Maike|id2@second   |id2@first.com |id2_3@first.com|
+---+---+-----+-------------+--------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to do it deterministically in Spark, you must have some rule to determine which email is first and which is second. The row order in the CSV  file (not having a specified column for row number) is a bad rule when you work with Spark, because every row may go to a different node, and then you will cannot see which of rows was first or second.

In the following example, I assume that the rule is the alphabetical order, so I collect all the emails into one array using `collect_set` and then sort them using `array_sort`.

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('1', 'id1@first.com', 'john'),
     ('2', 'id2@first.com', 'Maike'),
     ('2', 'id2@second', 'Maike'),
     ('1', 'id1@second.com', 'john')],
    ['id', 'email', 'name'])
```

Script:

```py
emails = F.array_sort(F.collect_set('email'))
df = df.groupBy('id', 'name').agg(
    emails[0].alias('email0'),
    emails[1].alias('email1'),
)
df.show()
# +---+-----+-------------+--------------+
# | id| name|       email0|        email1|
# +---+-----+-------------+--------------+
# |  2|Maike|id2@first.com|    id2@second|
# |  1| john|id1@first.com|id1@second.com|
# +---+-----+-------------+--------------+
```

---

If you had a row number, something like...

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('1', '1', 'id1@first.com', 'john'),
     ('2', '2', 'id2@first.com', 'Maike'),
     ('3', '2', 'id2@second', 'Maike'),
     ('4', '1', 'id1@second.com', 'john')],
    ['row_number', 'id', 'email', 'name'])
```

You could use something like below options:

```py
emails = F.array_sort(F.collect_set(F.struct(F.col('row_number').cast('long'), 'email')))
df = df.groupBy('id', 'name').agg(
    emails[0]['email'].alias('email0'),
    emails[1]['email'].alias('email1'),
)
df.show()
# +---+-----+-------------+--------------+
# | id| name|       email0|        email1|
# +---+-----+-------------+--------------+
# |  2|Maike|id2@first.com|    id2@second|
# |  1| john|id1@first.com|id1@second.com|
# +---+-----+-------------+--------------+
```

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

w = W.partitionBy('id', 'name').orderBy('row_number')
df = (df
    .withColumn('_rn', F.row_number().over(w))
    .filter('_rn <= 2')
    .withColumn('_rn', F.concat(F.lit('email'), '_rn'))
    .groupBy('id', 'name')
    .pivot('_rn')
    .agg(F.first('email'))
)
df.show()
# +---+-----+-------------+--------------+
# | id| name|       email1|        email2|
# +---+-----+-------------+--------------+
# |  1| john|id1@first.com|id1@second.com|
# |  2|Maike|id2@first.com|    id2@second|
# +---+-----+-------------+--------------+
```